# MSFT SQL Server rejecting specific domain logins

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication, active-directory

We use a centralized MSFT SQL Server for database storage. These databases are accessed using domain authentication, which has worked flawlessly until recently. Now, when attempting to authenticate using domain credentials, certain users are given a failure message. The corresponding error on the server is like so:

[Appears to be authenticating using integrated machine accounts, rather than provided domain authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw1Bj.png)

It looks like its using the integrated machine authentication, rather than the domain authentication provided during connection process. This same process works for a few other accounts on the domain, but there are no consistencies in which ones work and which ones do not.

I've tried dropping the SQL server from the domain, and readding it to establish the trust once more - but this has not helped.

We have the groups these users are a member of associated with SQL server, with the SA account to allow admin rights.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: More information: The failure indicates a state of '5', which is for invalid userid. This is not possible, as known good user accounts are being used.

Comment: Little bit more information; turns out all Windows Authentication is failing. I'd thought certain accounts were working, but it looks like whats happening is that integrated Windows NT security (machine auth) is being used, and working for some machines.

Comment: The built in SA account, should be disabled. Are your users indirectly in a AD or SQL group that is using the SA account for access. Maybe someone disabled the SA account, or changed the password. Also if using the SA account, it is not a domain account.

Comment: The SA account is mapped to the AD groups that we've associated with the SQL server. The SA account is not disabled, as we're using this as a fallback due to AD authentication not functioning.

Comment: Pulling the SQL server off the domain and adding it back really messes it up. You might have to re-install SQL server, to get the link to AD working again. Have you tried to set the spn's again, see here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731241(ws.10).aspx

Comment: Chuck, thanks for your help on this. I didn't want to remove it from the domain to readd it, but thought perhaps this would resolve a lost trust issue - it didn't. I am willing to attempt the setspn commands, but I have a quick question. Is the setspn -r hostname command issued from the domain controller, or the server itself?

Comment: I usually run it directly on the server that is having the issues, it updates AD anyway. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Tried this from the server itself, and it was successful. However, domain authentication is still not functioning. When attempting to use the domain username and password, the error reported by SQL is that a matching username could not be found for DOMAIN\MACHINENAME but it should not be using NTLM auth, should be using the domain username and password provided.